# Why can the compiler not optimize away the access to this const parameter?

Tags: c++, assembly, gcc, optimization, compiler-optimization

I have already searched for some answers on Google and Stack Overflow, and I am aware that compilers cannot assume that functions won't modify arguments passed through const references, as these functions might obtain a non-const reference via `const_cast`. However, doing this is undefined behavior when the original object itself is defined as `const`. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast)

> Modifying a const object through a non-const access path and referring to a volatile object through a non-volatile glvalue results in undefined behavior.

For the following code

```
void fun(const int&);

int f1() {
    const int i = 3;
    fun(i);
    return i;
}

static int bar(const int i) {
    fun(i);
    return i;
}

int f2() {
    return bar(3);
}
```

Both GCC and Clang are capable of optimizing the function `f1()` to directly return `3`, as the compilers consider that calling `fun(i)` won't modify the value of `i`, since such an action would result in undefined behavior.  However, both GCC and Clang are unable to apply the same optimization to the function `f2()`. The compilers still generate code to load the value of `i` from memory. Below is the code for `f1()` and `f2()` generated by GCC. [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/WGh5KK3aG)

```
f1():
        subq    $24, %rsp
        leaq    12(%rsp), %rdi
        movl    $3, 12(%rsp)
        call    fun(int const&)
        movl    $3, %eax  ! <-- Returns 3 directly.
        addq    $24, %rsp
        ret
f2():
        subq    $24, %rsp
        leaq    12(%rsp), %rdi
        movl    $3, 12(%rsp)
        call    fun(int const&)
        movl    12(%rsp), %eax ! <-- Load the return value from memory.
        addq    $24, %rsp
        ret
```

Even though the standard does not require that compilers must perform such optimizations, I believe compilers should have the capability to optimize `f2()` to directly return `3` as well. In my view, this would result in more efficient code (please correct me if I'm mistaken). When the compiler inlines the calling `bar(3)` into function `f2()`, it should be able to deduce that calling `fun(i)` will not modify the value of `i`.

Continuing with another example. When I replace the variable `i` in function `f1()` with a class type, Clang is still able to optimize it to return `3`. However, GCC opts to load the return value from memory instead:

```
struct A {
    int i;
};

void fun(const A&);

int f3() {
    const A a{3};
    fun(a);
    return a.i;
}
```

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/44bz1Mc7h)

Here is the code generated by GCC:

```
f3():
        subq    $24, %rsp
        leaq    12(%rsp), %rdi
        movl    $3, 12(%rsp)
        call    fun(A const&)
        movl    12(%rsp), %eax  ! <-- Load the return value from memory.
        addq    $24, %rsp
        ret
```

and Clang:

```
f3():
        pushq   %rax
        movl    $3, (%rsp)
        movq    %rsp, %rdi
        callq   fun(A const&)@PLT
        movl    $3, %eax  ! <-- Returns 3 directly.
        popq    %rcx
        retq
```

Why doesn't GCC optimize the function to directly return 3? Is it because GCC considers loading the return value from memory to be equally efficient as directly returning a constant?

Comment: I'm not a compiler writer, but it may just be a missed optimization path.  To paraphrase Chandler Carruth, sometimes compilers just run out of smarts.

Comment: GCC and Clang are both happy to optimize [in the case that they know for sure that `fun` doesn't do anything funny](https://godbolt.org/z/rEWvPeKjq), that seems like evidence that they're being conservative regarding something `fun` might do. Even though it "can't".

Comment: Related: [Why don't c++ compilers replace this access to a const class member with its value known at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70522927) - but in that case (with a `const` struct member), there are non-UB ways to generate an object with a different value.  Here there isn't; the underlying object is `const`, and a reload could only matter if the function changed it.  I thought there was an existing Q&A about missed optimizations where compilers don't assume that `const` locals keep their value, but I haven't found it.  This looks like a GCC missed-optimization.

Comment: Generally, `const` doesn't mean it can't change, it means *you* can't change it, and that differs between C & C++ and by standard version.  However, here I don't see how it might change by some other way, seems like a closed case but not handled for some reason...

Comment: @ErikEidt: That's what a reference-to- `const` or pointer-to-`const` means.  An object created `const` cannot change its value during its lifetime.  C++ formerly forbade fiddling with lifetime of `const` objects while they were being used, but due to a DR that workaround is now allowed.  (Being a DR made the change retroactive; there is now no standard version which prevents changing the value of a `const` object via lifetime fiddling, breaking existing compliant code :(.)

Comment: what did the gcc folks say when you asked?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Which DR do you have in mind for lifetime of `const` object?  Are you talking about things that might be sub-objects of a class, and placement-`new`?  (the C++20 change: https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/fd8ff6441f93024bd0ee6e03a03c08be8e1b5ce0).  In this case, the compiler knows the complete object is a `const int i` which it chose to put on the stack.  Are you saying that `fun(&i)` could make a new object in that space, and the later `return i;` should load that new object via the old name?  Or is it still just a missed opt but GCC is conservative because of other cases?

Comment: @PeterCordes I think since `i` is a complete `const` object, even if `fun(&i)` uses placement new to create a new object on the storage occupied by `i`, the original name `i` cannot automatically refer to the new object, because `i` is not transparently replaceable by the new object. The compiler can take advantage of this by assuming that the value of `i` will not change unless `std::launder` is used.

Comment: @Pluto: Yeah, I don't think that would be valid either since it's a complete object where the compiler can see the declaration, not just via a pointer or reference.  I hope ISO C++ doesn't allow anything to change the bytes in that storage because that would be silly.  My suggestion was the only thing could think of for possible lifetime shenanigans, not something I actually thought would be legal.